# Grab value from XML Feed with PHP

Tags: php

I have the following XML output from my website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <status>0</status>
  <item>
    <message>OK</message>
    <id>123</id>
  </item>
</result>
```

I'd like to grab the value inside `<id>` & store in a variable.

Is there a way to do this without using SimpleXML?

Comment: Use `DOM` extension with `xpath`

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this:
See the official documentation:

XML Manipulation : http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

The problem is they are all much much more complicated than SimpleXML and nowhere as fast for random access

I would go with simplexml like this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <status>0</status>
  <item>
    <message>OK</message>
    <id>123</id>
  </item>
</result>';

$xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $xmlcont->item->id;

Output : 123
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Bilal - this worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Refer This
[Using DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php)

[Using simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)